# _A is undefined while trying to iterate through a array on button click

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

In my ionic app i have a array of Users, which have unique users ID( user data comes from http GET, that selects all users in my database), at the same time i have another table in my database that is called Eletroneuro, and each row has a user ID so i can link the eletroneuro row's to each users, some users have more than 1 eletroneuro row. I'm trying to achieve this with an Array of arrays in my typescript file, but im getting "A is undefined on browser, no errors while doing ionic serve tho.

HTML PAGE

```
 <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Time</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime displayFormat="DD-MM-YYYY" [(ngModel)]="data"></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>


    <button ion-button (click)="mostrarTabelaPacientesDb(data)">Mostrar Fichas</button>
    <div *ngFor="let user of users">
        <ion-row>
           <ion-col col-6>
            {{user.pacientenome}}                       
          </ion-col>          
          <ion-col col-6>
            {{user.pacientedataexame}} 

          </ion-col>   
        </ion-row> 
        <ion-row>
          <button ion-button (click)="mostrarEletroneuro(user.id)">Mostrar tabelas</button>
          <div *ngFor="let eletro of eletroneuros">

              <ion-row> {{eletro.musculonome}}</ion-row>

          </div>
        </ion-row>



      </div>
  </ion-grid>

</ion-content>
```

TYPESCRIPT PAGE

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-lista-pacientes',
  templateUrl: 'lista-pacientes.html',
})
export class ListaPacientesPage {
  data: any = {};
  users: any[];  
  eletroneuro: any[];
  eletroneuros: any[][];
  mostrarTabela: boolean = false;
  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public service: ServiceProvider
  ) 
    {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ListaPacientesPage');

  }

  mostrarTabelaPacientesDb(data: String){  

    for(let n of this.users) {
       this.mostrarEletroneuro(n.id)
       this.eletroneuros.push(this.eletroneuro);    

   }
    this.service.getListaPacienteByData(data).subscribe(
      data => this.users = data
    )

  }
  mostrarEletroneuro(id: number){
    this.mostrarTabela = true;
    this.service.getDataEletroneuroById(id).subscribe(
      data => this.eletroneuro = data
    )
    return this.eletroneuro;
  }

}
```

SERVICE.TS RELEVANT METHODS

```
getListaPacienteByData(data: String){
    return this.http.get(`${this.api}pacientesdb/${data}/`).map(res=> res.json())
  }

  getDataEletroneuroById(id: number){
    return this.http.get(`${this.api}eletroneuro/${id}/`).map(res=> res.json())
  }
```